# Startup command with variable settings

Tags: bash, environment-variables, dropbox, autostart, dbus

I have Xubuntu 16.04 for 2 days.

I am trying to set an entry in `Session and Startup`>`Application Autostart` that will set several bash variables and execute a command.

I have managed how to do it without variable settings. The entry that worked is this
`dbus-launch dropbox start -i`

But how to add variable settings?
My attempts have been these but failed:

```
dbus-launch DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="" QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE="" dropbox start -i
```

and

```
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=""&&QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=""&&dropbox start -i
```

and

```
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=""&&QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=""&&dbus-launch dropbox start -i
```

and

```
dbus-launch --sh-syntax 'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=""&&QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=""&&dropbox start -i'
```

---

These work well in the terminal not in the autostart:

```
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=""&&QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=""&&dropbox start -i
```

and

```
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=""&&QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=""&&dbus-launch dropbox start -i
```

---

I also tried to add the command

```
#!/bin/bash

DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=""&&QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=""&&dropbox start -i
```

to files `~/.xinitrc` and `~/.xsession`, but not succeed.

How to add the variable settings to the command in the autostart?

### Update

I found a solution but I do not put it as the answer because such a way of handling dropbox would be rather hacky. But as far as variables are considered, in a universal way, a solution was found.

Create a command in a $PATH directory.

*dropbox-fix*

```
#!/bin/bash

DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=
QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=
dropbox start -i
```

Add the entry in `Session and Startup`>`Application Autostart`

```
dbus-launch dropbox-fix
```

Comment: Try replacing `&&` by newlines (i.e. one command per line). Do you really set the variables to the empty string (`""`) or did you leave the values out for readability?

Comment: @danzel Yes. This is a way to fix two issues of dropbox: lack of dropbox indicate icon and dropbox menu and the crashed window of selective download. I found them on the internet. But after your question, I thought that they are not clean. Sth like a hack. So I have no way and will risk a little.